Is it safe to take the reference of an inline fixed size buffer of a struct to use in a Span in C#?
Consider the following struct:
internal struct WriteBuffer64
{
    private const int INLINE_BUFFER_SIZE = 64;
    private unsafe fixed byte buffer[INLINE_BUFFER_SIZE];
    private int used;

    public unsafe Span<byte> GetWriteSpan(int toWrite)
    {
        if (used + toWrite > INLINE_BUFFER_SIZE)
            throw new Exception();

        int offset = used;
        used += toWrite;
        return MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan(ref buffer[offset], toWrite);
    }

    public unsafe ReadOnlySpan<byte> AsSpan()
    {
        return MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan(ref buffer[0], used);
    }
}

I'm wondering whether this is safe to do. Instances of WriteBuffer may be located on the heap when boxed or when used in class types. So, I assume a native byte* pointer (pointing to the fixed buffer) may not be safe to use.
But how about Span? Is it capable to interpret this as a reference to a managed object? More generally, how does the magic with references to managed objects in Spans work?
UPDATE
To be more specific:
SAFE CASE
byte[] utf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello World!");
WriteBuffer64 buffer = new WriteBuffer64();
BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt32BigEndian(buffer.GetWriteSpan(sizeof(int)), utf8.Length);
utf8.AsSpan().CopyTo(buffer.GetWriteSpan(utf8.Length));

using Stream file = File.OpenWrite("output.bin");
file.Write(buffer.AsSpan());

SAFE, TOO?
public class Encoder
{
    private WriteBuffer64 buffer = new WriteBuffer64();

    public void Encode()
    {
        byte[] utf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello World!");
        BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt32BigEndian(buffer.GetWriteSpan(sizeof(int)), utf8.Length);
        utf8.AsSpan().CopyTo(buffer.GetWriteSpan(utf8.Length));
    }

    public void WriteToFile()
    {
        using Stream file = File.OpenWrite("output.bin");
        file.Write(buffer.AsSpan());
    }
}

var encoder = new Encoder();
encoder.Encode();
encoder.WriteToFile();


The Span<T> type is a ref struct type, and a ref struct type are allocated on the stack and can't escape to the managed heap.

Have you considered using InlineArray https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-12.0/inline-arrays

@Charlieface Yes. Would it solve anything in my context?

@shingo Does this fact implictly answer (parts of) my question somehow?

Yes, byte* is unsafe because you can keep the pointer even if the target memory becomes unavailable. Span<T> are allocated on the stack, so its lifetime will not be longer than the fixed buffer.

Yes it obviates the need for fixing (which messes with GC) and the need for using unsafe as it implicitly converts to a span.

If it is a public struct that can be freely instantiated and allocated on the stack, it won't be safe. This example illustrates why.
void Main() {
    var span = GetMeSpan();
    var beforeMethodCall = string.Join(" ", span.ToArray());
    Console.WriteLine("Just to use the stack");
    var afterMethodCall = string.Join(" ", span.ToArray());

    Console.WriteLine(beforeMethodCall);
    Console.WriteLine(afterMethodCall);
}

Span<byte> GetMeSpan() {
    var buffer = new WriteBuffer64();
    return buffer.GetWriteSpan(42);
}

Output:
Just to use the stack
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 13 70
64 203 27 0 0 0 0 0 10 159 84 231 254 7 0 0 160 170 74 66 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 192 0 206 65 1 0 0 0 13 70

However, If you make the struct a private nested type inside a class that is used only as a field in that class (similar to your updated version of question inside the Encoder class), I think that it's safe because

The managed pointer that the Span holds will be updated if the class instance holding the struct is relocated on the heap during GC.

The managed pointer will keep the object holding the struct from being GCed.



EDIT:
This is corroborated by the docs for MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan<T>:

This method can be useful if part of a managed object represents a
fixed array.

You might want to check the warning/fine print there too.

Demo for the last points (compile/run in Release):
public static unsafe void Main() {
    // some allocations so GC moves our object in memory
    for (int i = 0; i < 10_000; i++) {
        new Tuple<int>(i);
    }

    const int INSTANCES_COUNT = 5;
    const int INDEX_LIVE = 1;
    
    var arr = new StructHolder[INSTANCES_COUNT];
    var arrWeakReferences = new WeakReference[INSTANCES_COUNT];

    for (int i = 0; i < INSTANCES_COUNT; i++) {
        arr[i] = new StructHolder();
        arrWeakReferences[i] = new WeakReference(arr[i]);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Heap object holding the struct: " + *(IntPtr*)Unsafe.AsPointer(ref arr[INDEX_LIVE]));
    // e.g. 5449393336
    var span = arr[INDEX_LIVE].GetWriteSpan(8);
    Console.WriteLine("Address of struct inside object: " + (IntPtr)Unsafe.AsPointer(ref span[0]));
    // e.g. 5449393344
    // 8bytes larger on 64bit - one pointer (for MethodTable of the object)
    Console.WriteLine("----");
    span.Fill(42);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("-", span.ToArray()));

    for (int i = 0; i < INSTANCES_COUNT; i++) {
        arr[i] = null;
    }

    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();

    Console.WriteLine("----");
    Console.WriteLine("After GC");

    for (int i = 0; i < INSTANCES_COUNT; i++) {
        Console.WriteLine($"{i} - Is GC Alive? - {arrWeakReferences[i].IsAlive}");
        if (arrWeakReferences[i].IsAlive) {
            // arr[i] is now a null reference...so we get the object this way
            var structHolder = arrWeakReferences[i].Target;
            Console.WriteLine("Heap object holding the struct: " + *(IntPtr*)Unsafe.AsPointer(ref structHolder));
            // e.g. 5398115416 -> 
            // if different - tweak GC dummy code above or rerun
            Console.WriteLine("Address of struct inside object: " + (IntPtr)Unsafe.AsPointer(ref span[0]));
            // e.g. 5398115424 - off by 8bytes again, but moved
        }
        // last one could be kept alive if not in Release mode
    }

    Console.WriteLine("-----------");
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("-", span.ToArray()));
}

public class StructHolder {
    private WriteBuffer64 _buffer = new();
    public Span<byte> GetWriteSpan(int toWrite) => _buffer.GetWriteSpan(toWrite);

    private struct WriteBuffer64 {
        private const int INLINE_BUFFER_SIZE = 64;
        private unsafe fixed byte buffer[INLINE_BUFFER_SIZE];
        private int used;
        public unsafe Span<byte> GetWriteSpan(int toWrite) {
            if (used + toWrite > INLINE_BUFFER_SIZE)
                throw new Exception("");

            int offset = used;
            used += toWrite;
            return MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan(ref buffer[offset], toWrite);
        }
    }
}

Example output:
Heap object holding the struct: 5461591448
Address of struct inside object: 5461591456
----
42-42-42-42-42-42-42-42
----
After GC
0 - Is GC Alive? - False
1 - Is GC Alive? - True
Heap object holding the struct: 5398109720
Address of struct inside object: 5398109728
2 - Is GC Alive? - False
3 - Is GC Alive? - False
4 - Is GC Alive? - False
-----------
42-42-42-42-42-42-42-42


I'm not sure, what you mean by the managed pointer, and it's actually part of my question: Is the pointer, which is stored in the Span, treated as a managed or native pointer.

@uebe it's a managed pointer. See updated answer and demo code.

Thanks a lot for your efforts and explanations. I tried your code and variations, but whenever I execute it, the live instance never moves in memory (addresses remain the same) (.NET 6/8 release mode).
I think, it's a very good approach to my question, but as of now, I'm unable to provoke object movement. Do you have any more hints, what might prevent the object from being moved during GC?

@uebe modified answer with some minimal code to ensure GC moves memory..was working under LINQPad (not fresh Console App) cause of some "garbage" inherent being created by LINQPad I guess

Thanks! Works now! Quite impressive, how GC manages to adjust the address of the Span on the stack. And I'm still curious, how it actually works under the hood...

@uebe hth. This blog post helped me the most in understanding how things work with spans. You can check this book too.
